# How to stripslashes all the items of an array at once?

Tags: php

I need to `stripslashes` all items of an array at once.

Any idea how can I do this?

Comment: Beware that most answers so far will blindly cast everything to string. That can be a pro or a con depending on your needs.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
foreach ($your_array as $key=>$value) {
$your_array[$key] = stripslashes($value);
}
```

---

or for many levels array use this :

```
function stripslashes_deep($value)
{
    $value = is_array($value) ?
                array_map('stripslashes_deep', $value) :
                stripslashes($value);

    return $value;
}


$array = array("f\\'oo", "b\\'ar", array("fo\\'o", "b\\'ar"));
$array = stripslashes_deep($array);

print_r($array);
```

Comment: I can't possibly give you enough upvotes for this :) After I have spent whole day trying every solution I could find and think of (in both jQuery and php) to solve damn double quote escaping of damn json object, your solution worked like a charm!! :)

Answer (score 13):

For uni-dimensional arrays, `array_map` will do:

```
$a = array_map('stripslashes', $a);
```

For multi-dimensional arrays you can do something like:

```
$a = json_decode(stripslashes(json_encode($a)), true);
```

This last one can be used to fix magic_quotes, see [this comment](http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php#95697).

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map):

```
$output = array_map('stripslashes', $array);
```

Comment: This gives warning: stripslashes() expects parameter 1 to be string,

Comment: @jdoef: So your array does not only contain strings?

Comment: not neccesarily. can't the script check if it is string and then only strip the slashes

Comment: @jdoef: Well, you could write your own function like `function foo(array $arr) { $ret = array(); foreach ($arr as $key => $val) { if (is_string($val)) $val = stripslashes($val); $ret[$key] = $val; } return $ret; }`

Answer (score 4):

I found this class / function

```
 <?php
/**
 * Remove slashes from strings, arrays and objects
 * 
 * @param    mixed   input data
 * @return   mixed   cleaned input data
 */
function stripslashesFull($input)
{
    if (is_array($input)) {
        $input = array_map('stripslashesFull', $input);
    } elseif (is_object($input)) {
        $vars = get_object_vars($input);
        foreach ($vars as $k=>$v) {
            $input->{$k} = stripslashesFull($v);
        }
    } else {
        $input = stripslashes($input);
    }
    return $input;
}
?>
```

on this [blog](http://www.fetchdesigns.com/blog/strip-slashes-from-arrays-objects-strings-in-php/) and it really helped me, and now i could pass variables, arrays and objects all through the same function...

Answer (score 0):

Parse array recursevely, with this solution you don't have to dublicate your array

```
function addslashes_extended(&$arr_r){
    if(is_array($arr_r))
    {
        foreach ($arr_r as &$val){
            is_array($val) ? addslashes_extended($val):$val=addslashes($val);
    }
        unset($val);
    }
    else
        $arr_r=addslashes($arr_r);
return $arr_r;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

## Any recursive function for array :

`$result= Recursiver_of_Array($array, 'stripslashes');`

code:

```
function Recursiver_of_Array($array,$function_name=false){ 
  //on first run, we define the desired function name to be executed on values
    if ($function_name) { $GLOBALS['current_func_name']= $function_name; } else {$function_name=$GLOBALS['current_func_name'];}
  //now, if it's array, then recurse, otherwise execute function
    return is_array($array) ? array_map('Recursiver_of_Array', $array) : $function_name($array); 
}
```

Comment: I think an answer from 12K user must be more descriptive and not so loud.